# "Normalizing" (de-skewing, re-scaling) images as preprocessing for OCR in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I have a bunch of scanned images of documents of the same layout (strict forms filled out with variable data) that I need to process with OCR. I can more or less cope with the OCR process itself (convert text images to text) but still have to cope with the annoying fact that the scanned images are distorted either by different degree of rotation, different scaling or both.

Because my method focuses on reading pieces of information from respective cells that are defined as bounding boxes by pixels, I must convert all pictures to a "standard" version where every corresponding cells are in the same pixel position, otherwise my reader "misreads". My question is, how could I "normalize" the distorted images?

I use Python.

Answer (score -2):

Today in high-volume form-scanning jobs we use commercial software with adaptive template matching, which does deskew and selective binarization to prepare the images, but then it adapts field boxes per image, not placing boxes on XY-location.

Deskeing process overall increases the image size.  It is visible in this random image from online search:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/skew-linedetection.png
Notice how the title of the document was near the top border, and in the deskewed image it is shifted down.  In this oversimplified example an XY-based box would not catch it.

I use commercial software for deskewing and image pre-processing.  It is quite inexpensive but good.  Unfortunately, I believe it will take you only part-way if the data capture method relies on xy-coordinate field matching.  I sense your frustration with dealing with it, thus appropriate tools were already created for handling that.

I run a service bureau for such form processing. If you are interested I can further share privately methods how we process.then